# is it possible to fix phonegap inappbrowser to load in landscape?

Tags: cordova, orientation, landscape, inappbrowser

I want to use the phonegap inappbrowser but it should load in landscape. My whole app shoud run in portrait mode so autorotation is deactivated.

Another thing i want to do is deactivating the tabbar on the bottom in the inappbrowser and just have a little X to close the fullscreen view of the browser. Any way to do this?

I know the possibility of android plugins but the main device i am developing for is iphone

Comment: Forcing the rotation of your application to two different aspect ratios is totally contrary to the spirit of the HIG. How does the user have any control over this? What benefit is yielded from locking your rotation in this way? Why would you force the user to manually turn their device to use a separate "mode" of your application when it would work perfectly fine in the native browser no matter which orientation? -- All that said, you can likely manually rotate the view yourself in the objc source.

Comment: i would do that because a SVG should be loaded in the inappbrowser and the only way to view it right is in landscape mode

Comment: i try to integrate this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ScreenOrientation but i am not smart enought to get the instructions :( the first part i put into my appdelegate.h, right? The Secon should be placed in the source file? which source file? Maybe i dont get it because of my english knowledge...

Comment: Why not transform your SVG using a CSS transform: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp - seems like a much simpler solution.

Comment: i get the svg dynamical via a URI Link so i think it would be easier simple display the URI link in the inAppBrowser. The SVG is not static, it changes because it shows what a machine in a company does actually

Comment: If you're displaying in a webview canvas element you can attach CSS to that element to do the translation. You really don't need to mess with the orientation of the view here.